# Where did I go wrong or where do I go from from here (Adam-Bashforth 2 Step LTE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to derive the LTE for the Adam-Bashforth 2-Step methods, I think I am close, the LTE should be $\frac{5}{12}\Delta t^2y'''(\xi)$, but I haven't gotten to that last step. I feel like I should use the MVT on the last step but I don't know how that would work because of the $1/2$ and the $1/3$. My work is below

\begin{equation*}
    \text{Trying to approximate }~ y'(t) = f(t,y(t))
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{\Delta t}{2}(3f(t_n,y_n) - f(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})), \quad \text{(AB2)}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \text{LTE} = \frac{2(y(t+\Delta t) - y(t))}{\Delta t} - 3f(t,y(t)) + f(t-\Delta t, y(t-\Delta t))
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}
     \frac{2\left(y(t+\Delta t) - y(t)\right)}{\Delta t} - 3f(t,y(t)) &= \frac{2\left(y(t)+\Delta t y'(t) + \frac{1}{2}\Delta t^2 y''(t) + \frac{1}{6}\Delta t^3 y'''(\tau) -y(t)\right)}{\Delta t} - 3y'(t) \\
     & = -y'(t) + \Delta t y''(t) + \frac{1}{3}\Delta t^2 y'''(\tau)
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
   f(t-\Delta t, y(t-\Delta t)) = y'(t-\Delta t) = y'(t) - \Delta t y''(t) + \frac{1}{2}\Delta t^2 y'''(\eta)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \text{LTE} = \frac{1}{2}\Delta t^2y'''(\eta) + \frac{1}{3}\Delta t^2y'''(\tau) \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{5}{12}\Delta t^2y'''(\xi)
\end{equation*}

$$ t\leq\tau\leq t+\Delta t, \quad t-\Delta t\leq \eta\leq t, \quad \text{and maybe } \quad t-\Delta t\leq\xi\leq t+\Delta t ~ ? $$

Thanks

Comment: In the combination of the contributions, you compute twice the LTE. You have to take back the multiplication by 2 that was used to remove fractions from the intermediate computation.

Answer (score 0):

One idea for the construction of this method is to approximate $y'(t)$ on $[t_0,t_+]$ by a linear function based on the values $y'(t_0)$ and $y'(t_-)$, where I shortened the point expressions to $t_-,t_0,t_+=t-\Delta t,t,t+\Delta t$. This, expressed in a Newton interpolation formula with divided differences, gives
$$
y'(t)=\underbrace{y'(t_0)+y'[t_0,t_-](t-t_0)}_{=p_1(t)}+y'[t,t_0,t_-](t-t_0)(t-t_-)
$$
Now integrate from $t_0$ to $t_+$, using $t=t_0+s\Delta t$,
\begin{align}
y(t_+)-y(t_0)&=\int_{t_0}^{t_+}[p_1(t)+y'[t,t_0,t_-](t-t_0)(t-t_-)]\,dt
\\
&=\int_0^1[(1+s)y'(t_0)-sy'(t_-)]\Delta t\,ds
\\&~~~~+y'[\tau,t_0,t_−]\int_0^1s(1+s)(\Delta t)^3\,ds
\\
&=\frac{\Delta t}2[3y'(t_0)-y'(t_-)]+\frac12y'''(\eta)\cdot\frac56(\Delta t)^3
\end{align}
I used first the mean value theorem for integration, and then the property of divided differences that $f[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]=\frac1{n!}f^{(n)}(\eta)$ for some point $\eta$ in the convex hull of the points $x_0,...,x_n$.